# Wget save cookies to bash environment variable

Tags: bash, cookies, environment-variables, wget

I know you can use wget to save cookies to a file

```
wget --save-cookies my-file.txt https://stackoverflow.com
```

is there a way to pipe `--save-cookies` straight to a bash environment variable?

Comment: What should bash environment variable hold after said operation?

Comment: The cookie name and value would be good

Comment: please note that it is --save-cookie*s* so it might hold more than one key-value pair, in which particular such pair are you interested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to /dev/stdout like that:

```
$ cookies="$(wget --save-cookies /dev/stdout https://stackoverflow.com)"
$ echo "$cookies"
# HTTP cookie file.
# Generated by Wget on 2022-01-24 17:59:48.
# Edit at your own risk.

.stackoverflow.com      TRUE    /       FALSE   2682374400      prov    0c002a59-7bf1-f8e9-2806-e50bb7e03a11
```

Comment: This requires `/dev/stdout` to actually exist in the file system. (`bash` only treats the name specially if it is the target of a redirection.)